# Teams Toolkit SPFX Application not rendering for accounts without Teams Admin or Global Admin

Tags: microsoft-teams, spfx, teams-toolkit

I created an SPFX application with the Teams Toolkit that utilises Microsoft Graph API to get data,after packaging and deploying the manifest folder to Teams Admin Center, it renders well with accounts that have Teams Admin and Global Admin access but accounts without this access are unable to access the application as it shows an error as seen in the image[image: Error Details].
The Component ID and version in the message are speaking to the React-dom component id and version in the project.
Please i need suggestions on how to resolve this as i am not sure if its just a permission issue

I have tried updating my spfx version but that didnt work as i was already working with the required version of spfx and all other dependency versions

Comment: What happens if you try use the webpart in a regular page in SharePoint?

Comment: I just tried this and i didn't see the webpart  when I clicked on the add icon on edit of the page

Comment: most probably, your users do not have access to the cdn where the JS and CSS file reside. Did you build the project from source or use a already built sppkg?

Comment: The sppkg is generated when i select the deploy to the cloud option of the Teams toolkit, I don't quite understand what you mean by access to the cdn, can you please shed some light

Comment: Can you try adding "everyone" to have read access to the app catalog site collection and make sure that the package is published/checked in in the list in app catalog? This really looks like a permission problem for me

Comment: Tried this and it didnt work, I also have the same issue when I try to run it locally as well on the teams workbench

Answer (score 0):

You can raise an issue in https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues so we can support you better.

I tried to reproduce your issue but failed. The web part displays successfully for account without Teams/Global Admin in my side. Let's clarify the steps before the issue happens:

1. Create a SPFx project in Teams Toolkit and utilizes Microsoft
   Graph API to get data
2. Click 'Provision in the cloud' to provision
   the Teams app (with Teams/Global admin account)
3. Click 'Deploy to
   the cloud' to generate the sppkg and deploy it to SharePoint (with
   Teams/Global admin account)
4. Click 'Publish to Teams' to publish
   the Teams app manifest in Teams app catalog (with Teams/Global admin
   account)
5. Approve the submission in Teams admin portal
6. Install
   and open the Teams App in Teams with Teams/Global admin account and
   the web part displayed successfully
7. Install and open the Teams
   App in Teams without Teams/Global admin account and the web part
   shows error.

Could you help confirm whether you're having the steps above to reproduce the issue?

BTW, after deploying you should be able to use the web part with normal account in regular page in SharePoint. Maybe you can check whether everything is OK in SharePoint app catalog

[SPFx solution after deploy to SP app catalog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRMJB.png)